# Cannot get object methods work when manipulating DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dom

I am developing an RPG game as a hobby and a way to learn the language. Now working on inventory.

I am using Jquery UI to build modal dialogs. When it comes to inventory I have 2 main dialogs:  one showing character details and one showing details of a city when visited by player. Both of these dialogs contain divs with different Ids but same class = "bagpack". The objective is to reflect current items in player's bagpack by addressing divs by class and manipulating them without utilising div ids (saves some code and adds more flexibility).

When it comes to inventory items, I have object constructors and push elements into relevant inventory array via .push(new Sword). Each item has some methods, namely, click, mousehover, mouseout - this will be critical for the problem I am facing.

So, when user opens city dialog or character details dialog then gameConfig.inventory.draw('bagpack') is called and div .bagpack gets redrawn based on which objects are in the  bagpack array. DOM is adjusted accordingly, but player obviously sees the effect only in modal dialog he is viewing.

Here is the code:

```
inventory: { //object within an object

    market: [],
    bagpack: [],
    active: [],
    arrows: [], 

    draw: function(inventoryArray, itemType){

    $('.'+inventoryArray).empty();

        gameConfig.inventory[inventoryArray].sort(function(a, b){ //sort array alphabetically
          var nameA=a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.name.toLowerCase()
          if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
              return -1 
              if (nameA > nameB)
                  return 1
                  return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
         });    

        if (itemType === undefined){ //array items will not be filtered
            for(i=0; i<gameConfig.inventory[inventoryArray].length; i++) {
              var item = gameConfig.inventory[inventoryArray][i];
              item.div = $("<div/>");
              item.div.addClass("inventoryItem");
              item.div.css({"background-color": item.backgroundColor});          
              item.div.css({"background-image":"url('"+item.icon+"')"});
              item.div.get(0).obj = item; //link DOM elemnt to an object
                item.div.click(function(){
                  this.obj.clicked();
                });
                item.div.mouseover(function() {
                  this.obj.getInfo();
                });
                item.div.mouseout(function() {
                  this.obj.mouseLeft();
                });

              item.div.appendTo('.'+inventoryArray);
            }


        } else { //array items will be filtered



        }


    }


}
```

What happens is:

1. I get items divs (background image, color, etc) displayed in both modal dialogs, no problems around this
2. Now, when it comes to methods, I face strange behavior. It appears that in one modal dialog methods are working, and in another modal dialog the following error is encountered: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseLeft' of undefined

I do not entirely understand what is happening and why in one case objects found in array are handled OK and in another case their methods get lost.

Comment: The error means `this.obj` is undefined. I suggest using `console.log(this)` and inspect it to see what's happening

Comment: @Oriol Indeed, in one case this.obj returns an object (in cases when methods work) and in another case it results in undefined (when methdos do not work). So there is a problem linking the div to an object?

Comment: inspect this in your dev console: gameConfig.inventory[inventoryArray] ..

also, you might find item.div.data('obj', item) to be better suited for linking objects to elements.

Comment: @Clayton Smith: gameConfig.inventory[inventoryArray] returns a valid array. Also, I get valid elements drawn (images, colors, etc). The linking is apparently an issues indeed. I tried item.div.data('obj', item); but now linking does not work in both modal dialogs. Do I need to adjust draw function somehow?

Comment: if you use the data method, you would need to change "this.obj" to something like $(this).data('obj').mouseLeft();  I'm not really sure if that will help though.  I'm wondering if the length value is incorrect on the array somehow? if you're accessing an element that doesn't exist on the array it'll return undefined.  is the value "i" getting modified anywhere else? try changing "for (i=0" to "for(var i=0"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Clayton Smith the problem was solved.

I did a crappy way of storing in .obj and now used a proper way.  This code solved it:

```
item.div.data('obj', item);
item.div.click(function(){
    $(this).data('obj').clicked();

});
```

Methods of an object are now correctly handled in multiple locations in DOM